# Copy attachment from todays received email to folder with python

Tags: python, outlook, outlook-filter

I have a script which copies an attachment from outlook to a folder on my laptop. So far so good, if I only have one email with the defined Subject and Attachment everything works fine. Today I realized that there's a problem when I have a newer and an older email with the same subject and attachment name in my inbox - it looks like it randomly takes the old or the new one.

Question: Is there a way to tell the script to either always take the youngest mail or take the mail received today?
I tried around with GetLast() and GetFirst(), what I found in stackoverlow, but wasn't sure where to add it exactly (my trys resulted in errors). Anyone having an idea?

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import datetime as date

outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")
all_inbox = inbox.Items
val_date = date.date.today()

sub_today = 'Email Subject'
att_today = 'Attachment.zip'

for msg in all_inbox:
    if msg.Subject == sub_today:
        break

for att in msg.Attachments:
    if att.FileName == att_today:
        break


att.SaveAsFile(r'C:\path\to\my\folder\Attachment.zip')
```

EDIT (SOLUTION):

```
import win32com.client
Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
olNs = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder("6")

Filter = ("@SQL=" + chr(34) + "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" +
          chr(34) + " Like 'ATTACHMENTNAMEHERE' AND " +
          chr(34) + "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" +
          chr(34) + "=1")


Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
Items.Sort('[ReceivedTime]', False)
Item = Items.GetLast()

for attachment in Item.Attachments:
    print(attachment.FileName)
    if attachment.FileName == "ATTACHMENT.zip":
        attachment.SaveAsFile(r"C:\path\to\my\folder\Attachment.zip")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetLast` and `GetFirst` are methods linked to `inbox.Items`

```
all_inbox = inbox.Items
all_inbox.Sort('[ReceivedTime]', True)
first = all_inbox.GetFirst()
last = all_inbox.GetLast()
```

Edit: As stated by @Dmitry Streblechenko you need to sort by ReceivedTime first the inbox.Items

Comment: Thanks for your answer - how do I use it in my code then? replace 'all_inbox' with 'last'? in "for msg in all_inbox:" ?

Comment: if you want the last message, you don't need the loop anymore. You need only `last = all_inbox.GetLast()`

Comment: GetFirst / GetLast do *not* return the newest or the oldest email, it all depends on the sort order.

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko Isn't the list sorted by time by default?

Comment: It is not. It is in whatever order the store provider decides to return the messages. Most likely they will be in the creation order. If you want a sorted list, you must call Items.Sort.

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko understood. I updated the code

Comment: Thanks, just realized, I need to set "Items.Sort('[ReceivedTime]', True)" to False :) Then it works! thanks

Answer (score 2):

*How about the following...*

---

```
import win32com.client

Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
olNs = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6)

Filter = ("@SQL=" + chr(34) + "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" +
          chr(34) + " Like 'Email Subject' AND " +
          chr(34) + "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" +
          chr(34) + "=1")

Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
Items.Sort('[ReceivedTime]', False)
Item = Items.GetLast()

for attachment in Item.Attachments:
    print(attachment.FileName)
    if attachment.FileName == "Attachment.zip":
        attachment.SaveAsFile(r"C:\path\to\my\folder\Attachment.zip")
```

---

*[Items.GetLast method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.getlast)*

*[Items.Restrict method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.Restrict)*

Comment: Thank you so much - I tried this version, however I am always getting the last but one, so today I am having these mails from 09/15. 09/14, 9/13 and like to take the one from yesterday, but it's copying the one from 09/14 :/

Comment: Added this little piece between Filter and GetLast and now it's working - thank you! :) 
Items.Sort('[ReceivedTime]', False)
Item = Items.GetLast()

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, never loop through all items in a folder - that is what `ItemsFind/FindNext` and `Items.Restrict` are for. In your particular case, call `all_inbox.Find('[Subject] = ''somevalue'' ')` to find a message with a given subject.

Secondly, you need to sort the Items collection first - e.g. call `all_inbox.Sort('[ReceivedTime]', true)` to sort the messages by the received date. After that, you can call `Items.Find` to find the newest message.