# Can we use outlook.attachments object in xlrd.openworkbook in python using win32com.client and xlrd without saving the excel file

Tags: python, outlook, xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(excel(1)) /// can we use this method without saving the excel from attachment 
'''

```
import win32com.client
import win32com
import os
import sys
import openpyxl
import xlrd

subjectLine = "Sample Scheduled Check Found a Problem"

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()

if message.subject == subjectLine:
    excel = message.attachments
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(excel(1))
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    no_of_rows = sheet.nrows
    first_data_row = sheet.row_values(1)

    print("mail found")'''
```

Comment: is this what your trying to do?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57931132/4539709

Comment: In the example from the above comment , they are saving the attachment. I want to know if there is a way we can use the attachment file without saving it first.