# Using Python to access outlook with win32com

Tags: python, email, outlook, attachment, win32com

I'm struggling with python integration with outlook using win32com.client.

All I am trying to do is get the most recent email from outlook and (at the moment) retrieve and print the name of the attachment

**The code I'm trying to use:**

```py
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespcae("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

message = inbox.GetLast()

att = message.Attachmets 

print (att.filename)
```

**Output**

`com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)`

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: CO_E_CLASSSTRING means COM object with the specified name is not installed. Did you actually install Outlook on the problematic machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The error is Outlook can't be found on the system but You have also misspelled **`GetNamespace`**, you have **`GetNamespcae`***

*Change `inbox.GetLast()`, to `messages = inbox.Items` then `message = messages.GetLast()`*

*Example*

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort('[ReceivedTime]', False)
message = messages.GetLast()

for attachment in message.Attachments:
    print(attachment.FileName)
```

*Here is another example with filter https://stackoverflow.com/a/57931132/4539709*