# Grab only latest received outlook email with python

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32

I am trying to save attachment from outlook email if it contains a specific string in the subject and also during the day there might be 2 or 3 emails with the same subject but the content in attachment changes. I wrote the code to save the attachment, however it saves attachments from all emails with this subject received today. Is it possible to save the attachment only of the latest receive email with this subject?

Here is my code:

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).folders("target folder")
items= folder.items

received_dt = date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
time_writing = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
items.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", Descending=True)

for i in items:
     RT = i.ReceivedTime
     Msgdate = datetime.datetime(RT.year ,RT.month, RT.day, RT.hour, RT.minute, RT.second)
     msgdate = Msgdate.strftime('%Y%m%d')
     if "apples" in i.Subject and received_dt == msgdate:
         for att in i.Attachments:
             att.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(input_folder + 'Apples_folder\\', 'apples_'+time_writing+'csv'))
         print('Apples attachment is saved')


     if "oranges" in i.Subject and received_dt == msgdate:
         for att in i.Attachments:
             att.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(input_folder + 'Oranges_folder\\', 'oranges_'+time_writing+'csv'))
         print('Oranges attachment is saved')
```

If I use `break` after apples block of code to save attachment, then it doesn't go to oranges, also when I am trying to enumerate and grab only the first email python shows:

```
This object does not support enumeration
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57931132/4539709

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Items.GetLast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.items?view=outlook-pia)

```py
items = folder.Items # needs to be uppercase IIUC
items.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", Descending=True)

most_recent = items.GetLast()

# you can call strftime directly on the ReceivedTime object
msgdate = most_recent.ReceivedTime.strftime("%Y%m%d")
```