# Download attachments from Outlook using win32com module

Tags: python, outlook

I would like to download multiple attachments from outlook. I have this code at this moment but have this problem.

In this pic:

[image]

you see that `attachment` variable has problem.

```
Error: pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', 
  (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Array index out of bounds.', None, 0, -2147352567), None)
```

Code:

```
import datetime
import os
import win32com.client


path = ("C:/Users/greencolor/Desktop/Autoreport/")
today = datetime.date.today()

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items


def saveattachemnts(subject):
    for message in messages:
        if message.Subject == subject and message.Unread or message.Senton.date() == today:
            # body_content = message.body
            attachments = message.Attachments
            attachment = attachments.Item(1)
            for attachment in message.Attachments:
                attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path, str(attachment)))
                if message.Subject == subject and message.Unread:
                    message.Unread = False
                break

download = saveattachemnts('PB report - next steps')
```

Answer (score 1):

*You cannot assign `attachment` to `attachments.Item(1)` then use it on for loop to iterating over `message.Attachments`*

*Try Example*

```
import datetime
import os
import win32com.client

path = r"C:/Users/greencolor/Desktop/Autoreport/"
today = datetime.date.today()

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items


def save_attachments(subject):
    for message in messages:
        if message.Subject == subject and message.Unread or message.Senton.date() == today:
            for attachment in message.Attachments:
                print(attachment.FileName)
                attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path, str(attachment)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    save_attachments('PB report - next steps')
```

*A better way would be to use filter*

```
Items.Restrict(Filter)
```

*https://stackoverflow.com/a/57931132/4539709*

Comment: this code downloaded all the attachments of that day, plus a lot of images. Probably I have to apply a filter

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming the message has attachments and unconditionally accessing the very first attachment. You need to check that `attachments.Count > 0`

Comment: Could you please show me the example using my code? I cannt get it work.

Comment: see the answer by @0m3r